# prop.test iteratively

Tags: r

I have a situation like this: first of all I have a data.frame:

> DF
>        COL1       COL2
>        29         1623
>        27         1600
>        30         1617
>        8          1620

Then, I have a vector like this:

> ```
>  [1]        [2]  
>  50         1602
> ```

What I need is to bind the first row of DF with the vector to have:

output

> [1]    [2]
>    29    1623
>    50    1602

On this output I would like to apply the prop.test using this code:

> prop.test(output[,1], output[,2], correct=FALSE)

I need to do this on the entire DF, so:

first: bind first row of DF with the vector
second: prop.test
then again
first: bind second row of DF with the vector
second: prop.test

This iteratively.

Any suggestion please?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
apply(DF, 1, function(x) prop.test( rbind(x, c(50, 1602) ) ,correct=FALSE ) )
```